# Extract number from the command line output by batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script that will submit certificate request and it will return a multiple RequestId in the CMD. I want the batch file to extract out all the numbers and store it in a file line by line with the filename called RequestID.

Here's the output of the commandline after executing the script

```
 C:\OpenSSL\bin>RequestCert.bat
 Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
 ...................................................................+++
 ...........+++
 writing new private key to 'xxxx'
 -----
 No value provided for Subject Attribute ST, skipped
 RequestId: 1892
 RequestId: "1892"
 Certificate request is pending: Taken Under Submission (0)
 Generating certificate request and key for xxxx
 ECHO is off.
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
 ........+++ 
 ...........................................................................
 ..........+++
 writing new private key to 'xxxx'
 -----
 No value provided for Subject Attribute ST, skipped
 RequestId: 1893
 RequestId: "1893"
 Certificate request is pending: Taken Under Submission (0)
 Generating certificate request and key for xxxx
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Please approve the certificates before pressing enter.
 Please approve the certificates before pressing enter.
 Please approve the certificates before pressing enter.
 Press any key to continue . . .
```

So the code should extract out the number after RequestId:

```
RequestId: 1892
RequestId: 1893
```

The file should have:

```
 1892
 1893
```

Afterwards it will take the first number and last number of the file and echo it out.
E.g Please approve the certificates from Request ID 900 to 920.

Here's what I've tried:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%b in ('"C:\program Files\command.exe"'|find 
"RequestId : ") do (
 echo %%b >> RequestID.txt
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing the batch code below I created the file `Input.txt` with the lines:

```
No value provided for Subject Attribute ST, skipped
RequestId: 1892
RequestId: "1892"
Certificate request is pending: Taken Under Submission (0)
Generating certificate request and key for xxxx
No value provided for Subject Attribute ST, skipped
RequestId: 1893
RequestId: "1893"
Certificate request is pending: Taken Under Submission (0)
Generating certificate request and key for xxxx
```

The batch code below was written into file `GetNumbers.bat` stored in same directory as `Input.txt`.

```
@echo off
del Output.txt 2>nul
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%I in (Input.txt) do if "%%I" == "RequestId:" if %%J == %%~J echo %%J>>Output.txt
```

On execution of the batch file from within a command prompt window with current directory being the directory with `Input.txt` and `GetNumbers.bat` by typing batch file name and hitting key <kbd>RETURN</kbd> there was no error displayed and the batch file created `Output.txt` with the two lines:

```
1892
1893
```

So coding task accomplished.

The **FOR** command processes each line from file `Input.txt` not being empty or starting with a semicolon.

It splits up each line into substrings (tokens) using normal space and horizontal tab as string delimiter.

The first space/tab delimited string is assigned to loop variable `I` and because of `tokens=1,2` the second one is assigned to loop variable `J` being the next character after `I` in [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

The commands in body command block of **FOR** are executed when at least 1 token could be assigned to first loop variable `I`.

The **IF** condition in body command block compares case-sensitive the first space/tab delimited string from current line with `RequestId:` to verify if this line contains the number of interest.

If this **IF** condition is true, the batch code expects that the second loop variable `J` is also set and has either just the number of interest or the number of interest in double quotes.

So a comparison is made which compares the value of loop variable `J` with the value of loop variable `J` without surrounding double quotes. The surrounding double quotes are also taken into account on comparing two strings with **IF** command. Therefore this comparison is only true if `J` has the number without surrounding double quotes.

The number without surrounding double quotes is appended to file `Output.txt`.

A bit slower but more safe would be following code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "DoubleQuote=""
del Output.txt 2>nul
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%I in (Input.txt) do (
    if "%%I" == "RequestId:" if "%%~J" NEQ "" (
        set "Number=%%J"
        if "!Number:~0,1!" NEQ "!DoubleQuote!" echo !Number!>>Output.txt
    )
)
endlocal
```

With this batch code loop variable `J` can have also no string assigned or a string on which first batch code would exit with a syntax error.

In both batch code blocks the file name `Input.txt` can be also replaced by:

```
'command line which outputs the text to process'
```

Please note that the surrounding straight single quotes make the difference for **FOR** if the string should be interpreted as file name of which lines to process or a command line to execute in a separate command process in background of which output to capture from handle **STDOUT** and to process line by line.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Really a long post and much to digest haha.